# Choice of Step in Implementation of Square Root Function

Tags: python, algorithm

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
step = epsilon**2
numGuesses = 0
ans = 0.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon and ans <= x:
    ans += step
    numGuesses += 1
print('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
if abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('Failed on square root of', x)
else:
    print(ans, 'is close to square root of', x)
```

This is the implementation of square root algorithm from the book **Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python**. How did we arrive at the value of step in `step = epsilon**2`?

Comment: I think is "arbitrary"... as long you have convergence, try with `step = epsilon *2` or `step = epsilon *.2` both work. Do you have any more rigorous details on **this** method used to approximate the root? I find funny that with `epsilon*2` is faster and more accurate than `epsilon**2`! [provided `epsilon = .01`]

Comment: mmm I think it is more a fake implementation, just a way to "crack" the square root... if you want to implement the square root compute the Taylor expansion, a binomial approximation, ... which are mathematically well defined methods. Adding a fix amount to `ans` just model it with an **arithmetic series** with initial value a, `ans = 0.0`, and common difference d, `step`, and then the n-th step is described by `n/2 * (2*a + (n-1)*d)`, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). So, don't make too many questions on this problem and move forward with the book;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that we're trying to design an algorithm that, given x ≥ 0, finds ans ≥ 0 satisfying |ans² − x| < ε, the success criterion that the author of this code has chosen. Let's suppose further that we have to use a linear search instead of one of the (much more efficient) classical methods.

Define δ = ans − √x so that ans = √x + δ is the true solution √x plus an error term δ. The left hand side of the inequality is

> |ans² − x| = |(√x + δ) (√x + δ) − x| = |(√x)² + 2δ√x + δ² − x| = |2δ√x + δ²|,

and we want it to be less than ε. It will suffice if |2δ√x| < ε/2 and |δ²| < ε/2 (standard CS theoretician's trick; don't do this if you care about constant factors), which is equivalent to |δ| < min(ε/(4√x), √(ε/2)). We can afford to take a step size of twice the right hand side.

This code sets step = ε², which can be either needlessly conservative or incorrect depending on the relation of ε and √x. You'll have to ask the author.